# Prior jQuery UI Dialogs become nonresponsive after opening a new Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having issues with multiple jQuery dialogs.  The first one opens fine - is resizable, draggable, etc.  However, when I open a second the first becomes unresponsive to dragging/moving/closing, even after the second one is closed.  What is the reason for this and how can it be fixed?

According to the jQuery documentation this should work fine (since stacking is supported).

Comment: How about you post some code so we can see what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work perfectly here:

http://jsbin.com/itira