# Problem with multiple jQuery UI dialogs and hyperlinks

Tags: jquery, user-interface, dialog

I'm having a problem similar to the one here: [Prior jQuery UI Dialogs become nonresponsive...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808454/prior-jquery-ui-dialogs-become-nonresponsive-after-opening-a-new-dialog).

Here's how the problem happens:
If I open one dialog and then a second dialog, and then close the second dialog, hyperlinks in the first dialog no longer work.

Here is the code for the dialogs:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function()
    {
        $("#PropertyDialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            position: ['center',100],
            resizable: false,
            height: 'auto',
            width: 700
        });
    });
    function ShowPropertyDetailsDialog(strPropertyId)
    {
        // set the html of the div
        LoadPropertyDialogHtml(strPropertyId);

        // open the dialog
        $('#PropertyDialog').dialog('open');
    }
</script>

<div id="PropertyDialog" title="Property Details">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function()
    {
        $("#PropertyImageDialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            position: ['center',75],
            resizable: false,
            height: 'auto',
            width: 650
        });
    });

    function ShowImageDialog(strTitle, strLinkUrl)
    {
        var dialogDiv = $get("PropertyImageDialog");
        dialogDiv.innerHTML = "<img src='" + strLinkUrl + "' alt='' width='600' />";

        $("#PropertyImageDialog").dialog"option","title",strTitle);

        // open the dialog
        $('#PropertyImageDialog').dialog('open');
    }
</script>

<div id="PropertyImageDialog" title="Property Image">
</div>
```

The `LoadPropertyDialogHtml` function does something similar to the first two lines of the `ShowImageDialog` - setting the content of the `PropertyDialog` div.

I can replace some of the link functionality by using `window.location` for normal links and `window.open` for new window links, but I'd like to get the hyperlinks to work (and I'd like to understand why this is happening).

Answer (score 0):

Could you do a quick check to see if there are any other DIVS on top of this dialogue? That could actually be an issue. In chrome, just right click > "inspect"  over the problem div, and it comes up highlighting an overlay / something that isn't your dialogue div, then that is the problem.